# MongoDB Compass Select Distinct Field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-compass

I'm trying to create an aggregation pipeline in MongoDB Compass for the field city in one of my collections. This is what I have so far:

```
[{$unwind: {
  path: '$city',
  preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
}}, {$group: {
  _id: null,
  distinctCities: { $addToSet: '$city' }
}}]
```

How can I add the number of occurrences for each cities? I would like to have an array that consists of objects with city and count.

Comment: I managed to iron out a solution that gives me the data that I need. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

**Query :**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    /** 
     * unwind city, if your desired response is just an array `[{city :..., count :... }]`
     * then you don't need to `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays`
     */
    {
      $unwind: "$city"
    },
    /** group on unique city's & count no.of occurrences */
    {
      $group: { _id: "$city", count: { $sum: 1 } }
    },
    /** group on all docs (without any condition) & push objects to an array */
    {
      $group: { _id: "", citiesAndCount: { $push: { city: "$_id", count: "$count" } } }
    }
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gjrz-cykpQN)

**Ref :** [aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/)

Answer (score 0):

This works fine in MongoDB:

```
 const aggregatorOptionsCity = [
    { $match: req.query },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$city',
        count: { $sum: 1 },
      },
    },
  ];
```

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to match with your question !! this would produce an array of docs/objects `I would like to have an array that consists of objects with city and count` if this means aggregation result array then question is misleading !! Also not sure why you're `unwinding` in question & not unwinding in answer ! If not first stage `$unwind` & last stage `$group` both are the same..